# extract common elements from lists in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

i have 3 Lists, for example:

```
  List l1 = [1, 2, 3, 55, 7, 99, 21];
  List l2 = [1, 4, 7, 65, 99, 20, 21];
  List l3 = [0, 2, 6, 7, 21, 99, 26];
```

and i expect the common elements:

```
// [7,99,21]
```

here is what i've tried but didn't work correctly:

```
 List l1 = [1, 2, 3, 55, 7, 99, 21];
 List l2 = [1, 4, 7, 65, 99, 20, 21];
 List l3 = [0, 2, 6, 7, 21, 99, 26];
 List common = l1;

 l2.forEach((element) {
   l3.forEach((element2) {
    if (!common.contains(element) || !common.contains(element2)) {
    common.remove(element);
    common.remove(element2);
    }
   });
 });

print(common);
```

plus, the number of lists is dynamic, so i expect to nest them like this, i have no experience with recursion so i couldn't do it or even know if it's better than nesting loops.

thanks for helping.

Comment: `Set s1 = Set.from(l1);
  Set s2 = Set.from(l2);
  Set s3 = Set.from(l3);
  print(s1.intersection(s2).intersection(s3));`

Comment: or even easier in just one line: `print([l1, l2, l3].map((l) => Set.from(l)).reduce((v, e) => v.intersection(e)));
`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One solution :

```dart
void main() {
  List l1 = [1, 2, 3, 55, 7, 99, 21];
  List l2 = [1, 4, 7, 65, 99, 20, 21];
  List l3 = [0, 2, 6, 7, 21, 99, 26];

  l1.removeWhere((item) => !l2.contains(item));
  l1.removeWhere((item) => !l3.contains(item));

  print(l1);
}
```

Result :

> [7, 99, 21]

If your number of lists is dynamic, then a solution is to count all occurences within all the lists, and retains only values where number of occurence is equals to the number of lists :

```dart
void main() {
  List<List> lists = [
    [1, 2, 3, 55, 7, 99, 21],
    [1, 4, 7, 65, 99, 20, 21],
    [0, 2, 6, 7, 21, 99, 26]
  ];

  Map map = Map();
  for (List l in lists) {
    l.forEach((item) => map[item] = map.containsKey(item) ? (map[item] + 1) : 1);
  }

  var commonValues = map.keys.where((key) => map[key] == lists.length);

  print(commonValues);
}
```

Result :

> (7, 99, 21)

Comment: Works fine! But if the List contains Map's: `List<Map>` it doesn't work!

Answer (score 24):

You don't need nested loops or recursion for this. Dart has `Set`s and a very nice `fold` method on `Lists`.

```dart
main() {
  final lists = [
    [1, 2, 3, 55, 7, 99, 21],
    [1, 4, 7, 65, 99, 20, 21],
    [0, 2, 6, 7, 21, 99, 26]
  ];

  final commonElements =
      lists.fold<Set>(
        lists.first.toSet(), 
        (a, b) => a.intersection(b.toSet()));

  print(commonElements);
}
```

Gives:

```
{7, 99, 21}
```

Further, this can be used no matter how many lists are contained in `lists`.

Comment: Works fine! But if the List contains Map's: `List<Map>` it doesn't work!

Answer (score 8):

A function to copy and paste in your project:

```
List<T> intersection<T>(Iterable<Iterable<T>> iterables) {
  return iterables
    .map((e) => e.toSet())
    .reduce((a, b) => a.intersection(b))
    .toList();
}

final commonElements = intersection(lists);
```

Comment: A small description of how this works would help!

Answer (score 1):

Or you could do:

```
  List l1 = [1, 2, 3, 55, 7, 99, 21];
  List l2 = [1, 4, 7, 65, 99, 20, 21];
  List l3 = [0, 2, 6, 7, 21, 99, 26];
  
  List uniqueItemsList = l1
    .toSet()
    .where((x) => l2.toSet().contains(x))
    .where((x) => l3.toSet().contains(x))
    .toList();
  
  print(uniqueItemsList); //[7, 99, 21]
```

Answer (score 0):

In case, if you want to use nesting loops.

```
 void main() {
  List l1 = [1, 2, 3, 55, 7, 99, 21];
  List l2 = [1, 4, 7, 65, 99, 20, 21];
  List l3 = [0, 2, 6, 7, 21, 99, 26];

  List result = [];

  for (final e1 in l1) {
    for (final e2 in l2) {
      for (final e3 in l3) {
        if (e1 == e2 && e1 == e3) {
          result.add(e1);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  print(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void main(){
List l1 = [1, 2, 3, 55, 7, 99, 21];
List l2 = [1, 4, 7, 65, 99, 20, 21];
List l3 = [0, 2, 6, 7, 21, 99, 26];
print(Set.from(l1).intersection(Set.from(l2)).intersection(Set.from(l3)).toList());
}
```

Comment: One liner using set intersections