# Dart/Flutter - Keep only duplicate items in List

Tags: flutter, dart

So I'm working on an app in Flutter, and long story short: I have 2 'filter options' which create 2 seperate lists. Now what I want is to use those 2 Lists and find the items which are present in BOTH lists and add that item to a third List.

Example:

List<int> first_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
List<int> second_list = [1, 2, 8, 9];

Result: [1, 2]

I know I could potentially loop through 1 list and then check with 'contains()' if the item is present in the other list. But it could be that 1 (or both) lists are empty and then my third list will be empty as I simply will never loop to add a duplicate item to the third list

Comment: Does this answer your question? [extract common elements from lists in dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59431806/extract-common-elements-from-lists-in-dart)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
void main() {
  List<int> first_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  List<int> second_list = [1, 2, 8, 9];

  final shared = [...first_list.where(second_list.contains)];
  print(shared); // [1, 2]
}
```

Comment: What if 1 of the lists is empty? Would that give an issue? Or would it just copy the 'not emtpy list'?

Comment: Try it out? It returns an empty list if any (or both) of the two lists are empty.

Comment: Okay. Thanks it seems to do what I need. I'll just have to check with some if-statements if lists are empty or not :)

Comment: Not sure I understand the need of an if. Wasn't the requirement that you wanted the elements which was in both lists and if one of the lists was empty you wanted the returned list to also be empty?

Comment: Nah I want if 1 of the lists is empty that it returns the value of the Non-empty list. But It works now with your thing and some if statements, so thanks. I'll accept your answer as soon as it lets me

Comment: Thanks, bro its working. but why added "..." three dots?

Comment: @gsm It is called a spread operator. You can call it on objects implementing `Iterable` and it will then take all elements from the `Iterable` and put them into the list: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#spread-operator

Answer (score 1):

What you need is intersection between two collections. Most likely it makes sense not to use lists, but rather sets of items.

I would solve this like that:

```dart
void main() {
  List<int> first_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  List<int> second_list = [1, 2, 8, 9];
  
  final shared = first_list.toSet().intersection(second_list.toSet());
  print(shared);
}
```

If you can work with sets, not with lists it would be even simpler:

```dart
void main() {
  Set<int> first_list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  Set<int> second_list = {1, 2, 8, 9};
  
  final shared = first_list.intersection(second_list);
  print(shared);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use intersection

```dart
  List<int> firstList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  List<int> secondList = [1, 2, 8, 9];

  final firsToSet = firstList.toSet();
  final secondToSet = secondList.toSet();

  final res = firsToSet.intersection(secondToSet);
  print(res);
```